# Sphinx Real Time index UPDATE statement not affecting all rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sphinx

Sphinx has me stumped. I have an RT index:

```
+-----------------+--------+
| Field           | Type   |
+-----------------+--------+
| id              | bigint |
| value           | field  |
| source_id       | bigint |
| hits            | bigint |
+-----------------+--------+
```

There will be multiple rows with the same source_id (unique IDs) that I want to update.

When I attempt to do multiple such as:

> UPDATE song_rt SET HITS = 109475 WHERE id in (11136,1194944,1194945,1194946,2661016,2661017);

It does not update the last two (2661016, 2661017), even though it says 6 rows updated. It works if I update the last two individually or together, but as soon as I add in one of the first 4, it will update those, but won't update 2661016 or 2661017. I even tried reversing the order I pass the IDs into the update statement with no luck.

If I attempt to update by source_id:

> UPDATE song_rt SET HITS = 109475 WHERE source_id = 11812;

I get the same 6 rows affected message, but the last
two still don't get updated.

I am running Sphinx 2.1.2 with 64 bit IDs enabled.

I've tested this both via code (PHP) and at the CLI. Googling and searching Stack hasn't turned up anything. Any ideas?

Comment: sounds like a bug. Perhaps the rows are in different shards. You could perhaps try http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxql-optimize-index to reduce to one shard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was in fact a bug: http://sphinxsearch.com/bugs/view.php?id=1773

I updated to rel21 as suggested and it resolved the problem.